# How to add color to parenthesis and brackets in vim using molokai

Tags: vim

I am using [molokai](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2340) in vim to code in python/html/css/javascript. When I edit python files (or javascript) parenthesis are not colored. This is not true for simple scripts (like molokai.vim itself) where parenthesis are colored gray.

I edited `molokai.vim` and added

```
hi parens guifg=#999999
```

and then I edited `.vimrc` and added:

```
syn match parens /[(){}]/
```

but parenthesis and brackets remain white.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Never use `:syn` to highlight all filetypes, there is `matchadd()` for this. Using `:syn` can easily break highlighting, `matchadd()` is an overlay.
2. Syntax highlighting is being overridden when `Syntax` event fires. More, it has effect only on the current buffer. So just `syn` in vimrc will never work, you have to use autocommands

   ```
   autocmd! Syntax python :syntax match Parens /[(){}]/
   ```

   (for python it is safe as parenthesis and figure brackets are not matched by any other syntax element).
3. In javascript parenthesis (`()`) are already matched by `javaScriptParens` highlighting group. Thus you have to use

   ```
   hi def link javaScriptParens Parens
   ```

   (in colorscheme). Braces are matched by `javaScriptBraces` and require similar command.
4. To determine what highlighting is used for specific symbol I place cursor on this symbol and launch

   ```
   echo 'Normal '.join(map(synstack(line('.'), col('.')), 'synIDattr(v:val, "name")'))
   ```

   , the last displayed word is normally what you need. If only `Normal` is displayed then symbol is not highlighted and you have to go 2., otherwise you have to go 3.
5. For universal solution disregarding currently used highlighting you may use `matchadd()` as I already said. But it is local to window so if you are working with multiple windows/tabs you can’t go without autocmd:

   ```
   autocmd! WinEnter * :if !exists('w:parens_match_id') | let w:parens_match_id=matchadd('Parens', '[(){}]') | endif
   ```

All autocommands are to be surrounded with

```
augroup HighlightParens
    autocmd! …
augroup END
```